# How to add group column in R dataframe based on time ranges

Tags: r

I have a dataframe in R (thousands of rows) containing data like this.

```
"id","ts"
1,2010-11-11 06:00:00
2,2010-11-11 06:01:00
3,2010-11-11 06:02:00
4,2010-11-11 06:03:00
...
11,2010-11-11 06:10:00
12,2010-11-11 06:11:00
13,2010-11-11 06:12:00
14,2010-11-11 06:13:00
15,2010-11-11 06:14:00
16,2010-11-11 06:15:00
17,2010-11-11 10:00:00
18,2010-11-11 10:01:00
19,2010-11-11 10:02:00
20,2010-11-11 10:03:00
21,2010-11-11 10:04:00
22,2010-11-11 10:05:00
...
```

I have data like the above for many days (11 Nov 2010 - 15 Dec 2010). Each day, ideally, has timestamp data (`as.POSIXct, tz = "UTC"`) in three time slots between the ranges given below. However, some days have data for one or two time slots only.

```
Slot1: 06:00:00 - 06:15:00
Slot2: 10:00:00 - 10:15:00
Slot3: 13:00:00 - 13:15:00
```

What I would like to do is, to add a group column (continous group number until 15 Dec 2010 data) based on the above three time ranges. The expected output is:

```
"id","ts","Group"
1,2010-11-11 06:00:00,1
2,2010-11-11 06:01:00,1
3,2010-11-11 06:02:00,1
4,2010-11-11 06:03:00,1
...
11,2010-11-11 06:10:00,1
12,2010-11-11 06:11:00,1
13,2010-11-11 06:12:00,1
14,2010-11-11 06:13:00,1
15,2010-11-11 06:14:00,1
16,2010-11-11 06:15:00,1
17,2010-11-11 10:00:00,2
18,2010-11-11 10:01:00,2
19,2010-11-11 10:02:00,2
20,2010-11-11 10:03:00,2
21,2010-11-11 10:04:00,2
22,2010-11-11 10:05:00,2
...
```

How this could be achieved in R?

Some reproducible sample data is here:

```
start1  <- as.POSIXct("2010-11-11 06:00:00 UTC")
end1    <- as.POSIXct("2010-11-11 06:15:00 UTC")
start2  <- as.POSIXct("2010-11-11 10:00:00 UTC")
end2    <- as.POSIXct("2010-11-11 10:15:00 UTC")
start3  <- as.POSIXct("2010-11-11 13:00:00 UTC")
end3    <- as.POSIXct("2010-11-11 13:15:00 UTC")
ts1     <- data.frame(ts=seq.POSIXt(start1,end1, by = "min"))
ts2     <- data.frame(ts=seq.POSIXt(start2,end2, by = "min"))
ts3     <- data.frame(ts=seq.POSIXt(start3,end3, by = "min"))
ts      <- data.frame(rbind(ts1,ts2,ts3))
id      <- data.frame(id=seq.int(1,48,1))
dat     <- data.frame(cbind(id,ts))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can extract hour and minute value from `ts` and use `case_when` to apply `Group` number.

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

dat %>%
  arrange(ts) %>%
  mutate(hour = hour(ts), 
         minute = minute(ts), 
         date = as.Date(ts),
         Group =  case_when(hour == 6 & minute <= 15 ~ 1L, 
                           hour == 10 & minute <= 15 ~ 2L,
                           hour == 13 & minute <= 15 ~ 3L),
         Group = (as.integer(date - min(date)) * 3) + Group, 
         Group = match(Group, unique(Group))) -> result

result
```

You can keep the columns that you want using `select` i.e `result %>% select(id, ts, Group)`.

Comment: Good!. What does '15 ~ 1L' symbol mean ?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. The same question as Juan and what if there is no continuous interval of 15 minutes?

Comment: @RonakShah: Another question, the logic `hour == 6 & minute <= 15~1L` and so on, provides group 1, 2, and 3 for the time slots in each day. I needed to have continuous group numbers from 1st day to the last day.  Does it make sense?

Comment: @RonakShah: My bad for being terribly unclear. I have edited my question. For each day, there are three time ranges (some regular and some irregular). Regardless of time-interval, for each day, I need to detect these time ranges, if they exist, assign a group number (1, 2, 3, 4, .....) and continue this last day.

Comment: Sorry, but all the 06:00:00 - 06:15:00 should not get 1. Group needs to be numbered based on number of time slots in a day. For example, on 11 Sep,  if all three time ranges exists as they appear in question then group should be 1, 2, 3. On 12 sep, if only slot2 and slot3 exist, then group be 4, 5. and so on. It's like counting these matching time ranges as appear in df and assign a (incrementing) group number.

Comment: @khajlk It would have been helpful if you would have included the specific requirements in the original post itself instead of adding them in comments. As per my understanding the updated answer should work, let me know how it goes.